# how to handle page not found or displayed exception

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am creating test cases using  web driver in java. I need to  catch situation if desired url is not navigated.Follow is the code

```
try{
    driver.get("url");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage);
}
```

My requirement is to handle exception in any case i am not able to get the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you will navigate to HTTP 404 page which contains some HTML. Which means you should handle it as "normal" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean present = false;
String pageName = driver.getTitle();
if(pageName.equals("Gmail: Email from Google")){
    present = true;
} 

Assert.assertTrue(present, "Error during loading of Landing Page");
```

It will throw the assertion error if required page is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`driver.get(url)` will not throw an exception if the url you included in `driver.get()` leads to a wrong page.
You will need to use `driver.getCurrentURL()` to check what the resultant URL is and compare it with your expected URL. 

 For example you can include this in the constructor of the class (PageObject if you are using a design pattern):

```
if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(loginURL)) {

                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "This is not the login page. Current page" + "is: "
                        + driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Another approach could be to validate the existence of element(s) that represent the expected page. If they aren't found, then throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You Can configure custom error handling page in your application.
It is a good practice to have your custom error handling or exception handling pages in your application.

In your case for 404 error

add following in web.xml

<error-page>

<error-code>404 </error-code>

<location>/error404.jsp </location>

</error-page>

//-------------------

and make a custom error handling jsp page error404.jsp

set isErrorPage="true" in page directive.

read more search google for isErrorPage page